# how to transform XML to XSL using python

Tags: python, django, xml, xslt, python-requests

I have a sample XML file like this:

```
    <contents>
  <part title="Lucene Basics(or Fundamentals)">
    <chapter title="Lucene Searching">
      <section type="internal" title="Lucene Scoring">
        <leaf title="How Lucene scoring works" seotitle="how-lucene-scoring-works">
        </leaf>
      </section>
      <section type="terminal" title="" seotitle="">
        <leaf title="hello world" seotitle="how-lucene-scoring-works">
        </leaf>
      </section>
    </chapter>
  </part>
</contents>
```

Now I want to convert this **XML into XSL format in python**! any ideas?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You cannot convert XML to XSLT. XSLT is also an XML format, but XML describes data, and XSLT describes tranformations. This task would mean to transform XML to XML - which can be achieved by XSLT which has been designed for this sole purpose.

Comment: my goal was I want to convvert XML to PDF in python.

Comment: OK, then you should have a look at [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) which does exactly that. It transforms XML files with XSLT to other formats (like PDF). It has a steep learning curve, but now you should know the google terms that will help you.

Comment: no basically data coming from a remote server (XML response). now I want to convert this XML response into PDF format in python. I am thinking this approach XML --> HTML --> PDF.

Comment: It's best to avoid the term"XSL" - for most people it means XSLT, but some use it to mean XSL-FO. I think you're using it to mean XSL-FO, and that has confused people. We don't get many questions on XSL-FO here for some reason. You can produce XSL-FO any way you like, but it's most commonly done using XSLT (not with a general-purpose language such as Python).